# set variable in heredoc section

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'm a shell script newbie, so I must be doing something stupid, why won't this work:

```
#!/bin/sh

myFile=$1

while read line
do
ssh $USER@$line <<ENDSSH
ls -d foo* | wc -l 
count=`ls -d foo* | wc -l`
echo $count
ENDSSH
done <$myfile
```

Two lines should be printed, and each should have the same value... but they don't. The first print statement [the result of ls -d foo* | wc -l] has the correct value, the second print statement is incorrect, it always prints blank. Do I need to do something special to assign the value to $count?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  echo Begin $line
  ssh $USER@$line << \ENDSSH
  ls -d foo* | wc -l 
  count=`ls -d foo* | wc -l`
  echo $count
ENDSSH
done < $1
```

The only problem with your script was that when the heredoc token is not quoted, the shell does variable expansion, so `$count` was being expanded by your local shell before the remote commands were shipped off...

Comment: This works! Thank you. Since you mentioned quoting the heredoc token, I tried that and it works too. Can you explain when I should and should not quote the heredoc token? Thank you.

Comment: If you want variable substitution performed then do not quote it. Quote it if you just want the bits shipped off. In your case it's a bit more complex because a shell is getting the input eventually, so they will ultimately be expanded, but you don't want it happening in the local shell.

Comment: Nice answer! I don't understand though why is `\ENDSSH` working. I don't think a reference of it in [Bash manual on Here documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)

Comment: Well, normally the heredoc lines have parameters, commands, and arithmetic expressions expanded. Quoting the first appearance of the marker symbol prevents that. So, the question becomes, do you want those expressions expanded, or do you want the text taken literally?